# OpenBSD run script on Startup

Tags: shell-script, cron, startup, openbsd

I was trying to run a .sh script on my OpenBSD machine on startup.

I've made the script executable using the `chmod +x` command. I've also added the script to cron via an entry reading

```
@reboot sh /dir/myscript.sh
```

(no quotes) as well as adding the script via and entry to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and making that executable as well, to no avail.

The script is a basic `echo "hello"` command. Any tips?

Note: I edited restart to reboot, as I misremembered exactly what I typed in

Comment: Where do you expect to see this `hello` string? If running correctly (with `@reboot`, not `@restart`), you would get the string mailed to you.  If running from `/etc/rc.local` (note the path), you would see it during boot.

Comment: Also, to what crontab did you add your command?

Comment: You have updated your question and corrected the `@restart` tag in your crontab. You still don't say what happens when this runs though. The owner of the crontab should get an email with the output of the job, including any error messages.  If this happens, can we assume that the issue has been resolved (and that GADR3's answer was correct, and that you may accept that as the correct solution)?

Answer (score 2):

To run a command on startup via crontab,  you should use `@reboot` string:

see `info crontab` or [`man 5 crontab`](http://man.openbsd.org/man5/crontab.5).

```
    string         meaning
    ------         -------
    @reboot        Run once, at startup.
```

Comment: [`man 5 crontab`](http://man.openbsd.org/man5/crontab.5) instead of `info crontab`, as the latter says nothing about `@reboot` on my OpenBSD 7.0 machine

Comment: @uxer Thanks, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Also note that the user who owns the crontab would expect to _get an email_ if the script produces any output or errors (they say they use a simple `echo "hello"` script).